# Get data from Outlook to Database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook

My project is to send fields before Visual Studio to Outlook Body in fields entered in the body after the reception of messages the user can modify the data sent in text fields on Outlook and sends the update data it will be saved in database that's possible to update data from outlook to Database ?

Comment: It is possible to read data from outlook but your question is not clear enough, what is outlook body?! Do you mean email body or what?

Comment: You certainly can, but can you show what you have tried so far, and what's not working?

Comment: VahidND yes i mean Email Body

Comment: i ask if there is some fontionnalities between outlook and Visual studio because i tried to programming on Outlook on VBA but it doesn't work and it's not easy to me thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have build a solution like that, I use it daily to read and file mail as part of my daily workflow.  But as others have hinted you need to be specific about what you need help with.

```
        If (TypeOf olItem Is Outlook.MailItem) Then
            Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(olItem, Outlook.MailItem)

            If olMailItem.Permission = Outlook.OlPermission.olUnrestricted Then
                strBody = olMailItem.HTMLBody                   'file:///C:/AttSave/header.png
            Else
                strBody = "Rights Protected fix if I'm not in debugger"
            End If

            For Each olAttach In olMailItem.Attachments
                If olAttach.Type <> Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olOLE Then
                    olAttach.SaveAsFile("c:\AttSave\" & olAttach.FileName)
                    'strBody = strBody.Replace("cid:header", "file:///C:/AttSave/header.png")
                    strCID = olAttach.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E")
                    If strCID <> "" Then
                        strBody = strBody.Replace("cid:" & strCID, "file:///C:/AttSave/" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(olAttach.FileName))
                    End If
                    lst_Attach.Items.Add(olAttach.FileName)
                Else
                    MsgBox("open this one via outlook")
                End If

            Next
            Me.webBody.DocumentText = strBody
            Me.txtSubject.Text = olMailItem.Subject
            If olMailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh Then
                Me.txtSubject.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Else
                Me.txtSubject.ForeColor = Color.White
            End If

            'Dim palSender As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry
            'palSender = mailItem.Sender
            Me.txtSentDate.Text = olMailItem.SentOn
            'Me.txtTo.Text = olMailItem.To
            olSenderA = olMailItem.Sender
            If IsNothing(olSenderA) = False Then

                'Dim olConItem As Outlook.ContactItem

                'olConItem = olSenderA.GetContact()
                'If Not IsNothing(olConItem) Then
                '    If olConItem.HasPicture = True Then
                '        Stop
                '    End If
                'End If


                Pa = olSenderA.PropertyAccessor
                'Debug.Print(olRe.Name & "stp= " & Pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"))
                Try
                    Me.txtFrom.Text = Me.txtFrom.Text & olSenderA.Name & " (" & Pa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E") & ")"
                Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
                    'Stop
                    Me.txtFrom.Text = olMailItem.SenderName & " (" & olMailItem.SenderEmailAddress & ")"
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Stop
                End Try
```

Comment: Thank you but i need to read BodyItem not File Item and for each textBox i save it n database on table Employees(Name,ImprovedAction,Challenge,dateChallenge,comment)